# Dovecot ignores userdb

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, email, email-server, dovecot

my Dovecot installation doesn't overwrite the quota_limit from the userdb. I already verified that it does successfully connect to my Mysql database, but my quota limit still stays at the default 100MB. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Dovecot.conf
====================================================

mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota
passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}

userdb {
  driver = prefetch
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_quota
}

protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = quota fts sieve
}


protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = quota
}

plugin {
  quota = maildir
  quota_rule = *:storage=100M
  quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+10%%
}

service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}

service dict { 
  unix_listener dict { 
    mode = 0660 
    user = vmail 
    group = vmail 
  } 
}

auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_verbose = yes
mail_debug =yes



dovecot-sql.conf.ext
====================================================

driver = mysql
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=****SNAP**** user=****SNAP**** password=****SNAP****
default_pass_scheme = SHA256-CRYPT
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%u';

default_pass_scheme = SHA256-CRYPT

user_query = SELECT CONCAT('*:bytes=', quota) as quota_rule FROM virtual_users WHERE email = '%u'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the quota plugin ahead of the userdb configuration. Most configurations are processed top down with the last value winning.

Comment: It didn't work but in the end I included the limit in the password query which works flawlessly: password_query = SELECT username as user, password, CONCAT('*:bytes=', quota_rule) as userdb_quota_rule FROM users WHERE username='%u';